# R shiny: how to write variable to cookies

Tags: javascript, r, cookies, shiny

It easy to write a fixed string to cookies using such as `Cookies.set(\'cookie_2\', \'value\', { expires: 7 })`
(see tutorial [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32353680/how-to-access-browser-session-cookies-from-within-shiny-app)).

But how can I save  `user` to `cookie_2`? Say I have

```
user = "Klay"
runjs('Cookies.set(\'cookie_2\', user, { expires: 7 });')
```

Is it possible to achieve this in one-liner? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Function is runjs('String') 
 so we made the string with our user variable, Like 'String'+variable+'String'

`user = "Klay"
runjs('Cookies.set(\"cookie_2\",' + user +', { expires: 7 });')`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but it did not work. Would you please advice more? Thanks.

Comment: `Error in "Cookies.set(\"cookie_2\"," + user : non-numeric argument to binary operator` is the error message.

Answer (score 0):

I finally come up with the answer as follows:

```
user = "Klay"
string = sprintf("Cookies.set(\'username\', '%s', { expires: 7 });", user)
runjs(string)
```

Comment: you don't need to escape `\'` you use double quotes.