# Is there a way to get the cookie value in RShiny application which we pass with redirect url

Tags: r, django, shiny

I am having web application in django framework and hosted n azure. I am having another web application in RShiny and its hosted in AWS.   We are having proper authentication process for the django application . Once a user will logged in django application we want that the user should be able to access the RShiny application without again asking for authentication . For this we were passing a token value in a cookie with redirect url of Rshiny .But  we were not able to fetch the cookie in the Rshiny app. Neither cookie is visible in developer tool of chrome.
The django code which we have written after a user clicks on the button

```
 def buttonclick(request):
    response=redirect('http://example.com')
    expires=datetime.now()+timedelta(seconds=480)
    response.set_cookie('token',value='tokenmmx',expires=expires)
    return response
```

"http://example.com" is the web url of Rshiny app

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32353680

Comment: Also cookies are domain specific. One website can't read cookies from other domains. Do both applications share a URL?